# Error while trying to run HBase map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am really having a hard time struggling with running Hbase-MapReduce with Hadoop.

I do use Hadoop Hortonwork 2 version. HBase version that I use is 0.96.1-hadoop2. Now when I try to run my MapReduce like this :

```
hadoop jar target/invoice-aggregation-0.1.jar  start="2014-02-01 01:00:00" end="2014-02-19 01:00:00" firstAccountId=0 lastAccountId=10
```

Hadoop tells me that is can not find the invoice-aggregation-0.1.jar in its file system ?! I am wondering why does it need to be there ?

Here is the error I get

```
14/02/05 10:31:48 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:adio (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:8020/home/adio/workspace/projects/invoice-aggregation/target/invoice-aggregation-0.1.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:8020/home/adio/workspace/projects/invoice-aggregation/target/invoice-aggregation-0.1.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
    at com.company.invoice.MapReduceStarter.main(MapReduceStarter.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I would appreciate any suggestion, help or even I guess why I am getting this error ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be specifying the class to use from the jar? That's not the error you're getting but I noticed you don't have it

Comment: Yes I know but last time I ran the jar it considered the class as an argument not as class and I don't really why !

Comment: Does this path exists in hdfs?
hdfs://localhost:8020/home/adio/workspace/projects/invoice-aggregation/target/invoice-aggregation-0.1.jar

Comment: No it does not, but I don't see why I do need it at all !

Comment: Dose your hadoop and hbase are on same machine?

Comment: ok i thought problem may be due to name resolution. above it is showing the localhost entry. If u can check for that have a look in config files.

Comment: What do you mean by name resolution ? And Where to check this out ?

Comment: in above error code it is showing the localhost instead of hostname of ur machine. so i am concerned to that. have u installed hadoop config files with localhost entry or using machine hostname?

Comment: "have u installed hadoop config files with localhost entry or using machine hostname? " I don't know. I've followed Hortonwork Guild to install a pseudo distributed hadoop fo development . But if you can tell me where to check this anyway ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47436/discussion-between-vikas-hardia-and-adio)

Answer (score 1):

Error is due to hadoop cannot find the jars on place.

Place the jars and re-run the job.
This will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, even I am not sure that this is the best solution I solved my problem by adding my application jar and  all missing jars to HDFS. Using Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 'myjarslocation' 'where_hdfs_needs_the_jars'. So whenever MepReduce throws exception telling you that some jar is missing in some location on HDFS add the jar to that place. This is what I did to solve my problem. If anyone has a better approach I would be please to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Include the JAR in the “-libjars” command line option of the `hadoop jar …` command

or check for other alternatives [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case error was fixed by copying mapred-site.xml to HADOOP_CONF_DIR directory